# Bug in C++ convex hull jarvis march algorithm implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, convex-hull

I wrote an implementation for C++ convex hull algorithm which should have been trivial. My code below follows formulas/approach from [the paperwork](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/compgeom/notes/01-convexhull.pdf). I use method called "Jarvis march".

It works fine for 20000 points and for much less in terms of performance, but if i randomize the order of input points array (using `std::shuffle`), i could see that sometimes it shows bug

[image]

After shuffling the input vector of same points:

[image]

(the green line is calculated convex hull for given black points)

You could think the bug is related to the "last" convex hull line. But it is somewhat different, which is observable here:

[image: I don't really know why the diagonal line looks different it is rendering bug i assume]

The code:

```
using namespace std;

vector<Point> m_in;

inline double cross(const Point &a, const Point &b)
{
    return (a.x * b.y) - (b.x * a.y);
}

// conterclockwise test
inline bool CCW(const Point &p, const Point &i, const Point &q)
{
//    auto a = p.x,
//            b = p.y,
//            c = i.x,
//            d = i.y,
//            e = q.x,
//            f = q.y;

// the same:
//    return ((f - b) * (c - a)) > ((d - b) * (e - a));

// the same:
//    Point va { c - a, d - b }; // i - p
//    Point vb { e - a, f - b }; // q - p
//    return cross(va, vb) > 0;

// the same, compact:
    return cross(i - p, q - p) > 0;
}


void Reset(vector<Point> &in)
{
    m_in = move(in);
}

vector<Line> GetLine() const
{
    vector<Line> res;

    Point l = m_in.front();

    for(auto &i : m_in)
    {
        if(l.x < i.x)
        {
            l = i;
        }
    }

    Point p = l;
    for(auto &pi : m_in)
    {
        Point q = pi;
        for(auto &i : m_in)
        {
            if(CCW(p, i, q))
            {
                q = i;
            }
        }

        res.push_back(Line { p, q });
        p = q;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Based on image:

[image]

Types, to be clear:

```
struct Point
{
    double x, y;

    friend Point operator+(const Point& a, const Point& b);
    friend Point operator-(const Point& a, const Point& b);
    friend bool operator!=(const Point& a, const Point& b);
};

struct Line
{
    Point a;
    Point b;
};
```

In the end, i don't see: where is the specific mistake in this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observer the fact how do you choose between `q` and `i`. Suppose you have this set up:

[image]

You want to choose `i` over `q` if `(i-p)^(q-p) < 0`. But you turn to the right instead. It is easy to see it if one chooses `p = (0,0), q = (1,0), i = (0,1)`:

```
i
|
|
p-----q
```

then `(i-p)^(q-p) = (0,1)^(1,0) = 0 - 1 = -1 < 0`, and one should choose `i` over `q`.

Also observe that you start from the point with the biggest `x` instead with the smallest.

**But all this doesn't matter. The algorithm works fine.** You can find it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1VKUZ-yN). It produces the right answer for your shuffled array.

Comment: @Croll Thanks for an interesting question. Did you find an error? Just interesting.

Comment: Yes. Check out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Correct the CCW test code:

```
inline bool CCW(const Point &p, const Point &i, const Point &q)
{
    return cross(i - p, q - p) < 0.0;
}
```

Do not manually loop through the input array to find the lowest X coordinate. Use `std::sort()` to sort input array by X coord. This does not break paper description of the method.

```
void Reset(vector<Point> &in)
{
    sort(in.begin(), in.end(), [](const Point &a, const Point &b) { return a.x < b.x; });

    m_in = move(in);
}
```

Rewrite code so it uses iterators (the confusing line from algorithm description was `q = p + 1` which was not actually implemented in code from OP). Try save the original approach to syntax, because no one likes C-style or C++98 samples widely overseen elsewhere.

```
vector<Line> GetLine() const
{
    vector<Line> res;

    if(m_in.empty())
    {
        return res;
    }

    auto    l = m_in.begin(),
            r = m_in.end() - 1;

    auto p = l;
    do
    {
        auto q = p + 1;
        if(q > r) {
            q = l;
        }

        for(auto i = l; i <= r; i++)
        {
            if(CCW(*p, *i, *q)) {
                q = i;
            }
        }

        res.push_back(Line{*p, *q});
        p = q;
    }
    while(p != l);

    return res;
}
```

The full code of my app is available on [Github](https://github.com/CrackHD/algorithms/blob/master/convex_hull/cJarvisHull.cpp) if you're interested.